# Which tags allowed to have columns class in Foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have grid structure using [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) version 5. I use some elements other than div to handle row or columns such as new HTML5 tags like nav, header, etc. Is this causes problems with grid layout?

I ask on this issue because there is a column seems to be not in grid. i.e its height is shorter than with its neighbour columns:

```
<header id="header" class="row">
      <div id="logo" class="small-4 large-4 columns">
        <div id="site-logo"><a href="/4test/drupal-7.28/" title="Home">
          <img src="http://localhost/4test/drupal-7.28/sites/default/files/ari_0.png" alt="Home">
        </a></div>        
          <a href="/4test/drupal-7.28/" title="Home"><span>Drupal Test</span></a>

      </div>
      <nav id="navigation" role="navigation" class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <div id="main-menu" class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <ul class="sub-nav"><li class="first leaf active"><a href="/4test/drupal-7.28/" title="" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/4test/drupal-7.28/blog" title="the blog">Blog</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/4test/drupal-7.28/node/4">About us</a></li>
        </ul>        </div></div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

In the code above nav height in the inspect element is very short and doesn not cover the all height of its neighbour columns.

The following screen shot demonstrate the situation:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

its working as you its expected the column is does not take the height of the row. It doesnt have a height set so it only is at tall as the children elements.

if you want the same height you have to set a min-height.

```
  <div id="logo" class="small-4 large-4 columns">
```

this div above will have the height of the children elements, as does the second column

[here is my test](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/411/)